# How to hide the Template Gallery on Google Data Studio landing page?

Tags: looker-studio

When users navigate to data studio home page https://datastudio.google.com/navigation/reporting it unfortunately shows the 'Template Gallery'? How can we hide this?

Users just want to see their reports.
The templates create noise and confuse users to thinking they are reports built for them. Messy.

If question not appropriate for stackoverflow, can you please suggest a different forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is currently not implemented.

Created a Feature Request by using the existing implementation in Google Sheets to demonstrate:

- [Option to Hide All Templates on Landing Page (like Google Sheets)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159562234)

*Vote on existing features by clicking on the "Star" icon (Top left).*

[image]